# Restore database using old control file

Tags: oracle, restore, rman, archive-log

Our environment has a full daily DB backup system, including the control file at 11 pm.

We had a case to restore the database in different environments but with maximum data to recover. Archivelogs are available on disk until the next day 5pm.

But, if we restore using the previous backup control file, it will restore until the last SCN, which is the backup time. So that, it won't apply the created archivelogs on disk after the backup untila the next day 5 pm.

How can we confirm that the DB has applied those archivelogs? Please advise me the way even if I have to apply something manually.

I believe that building DR have such circumstances by applying the differences in archivelogs after mounting, which is fine if we had to follow similar scenario. Thanks.

Comment: You just need to use `rman` to `catalog` the archive logs.

Comment: I cannot open the DB due to some missing files..
and i need to restore up to 5min or something before the problem.

Comment: Can you provide details on how you're doing the backup and restore, and what errors you're getting?

Comment: There's no errors.
I have backup with Control file taken by 10pm yesterday for example
And i wants to restore it using the same backed up control file then apply the archivelogs until today's 3 or 4 pm for example.
is it possible to apply logs not identified on the control file?